# Divide integer number into dynamic number of parts using php

Tags: php

I want to divide a number into n number of parts like follows

Input : $n = 4;$m =14;
Output should as : array(1=>4,2=>4,3=>3,4=>3);

i.e :

```
   $n           $m

   1          1+1+1+1
   2          1+1+1+1
   3          1+1+1
   4          1+1+1
```

Any suggestions or links would help a lot.

Comment: Sounds like: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it - this works in phpfiddle:

```
$n = 4;
$m =14;

$array = distribute($m,$n);
print_r($array);

function distribute($m,$n) {

    $div = floor($m / $n);
    $mod = fmod($m, $n);
    $result = array();
    for ($i = 1;$i <= $n;$i++) {
        $result[$i] = $div; 
    }

    if ($mod > 0) { 
        for ($i = 1;$i <= $mod;$i++) {
            $result[$i] = $result[$i] + 1;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```